# What is the parameter T.() in this lambda expression in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was taking a look on the apply scope function in kotlin and i had some problem understanding the synta

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit):
```

What i do not understand is the part inside the function, more specific

```
T.()
```

What does T.()  mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parameter that looks like this:

`someParameter: Something -> SomethingElse`

is a [*function type*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types). Just like how you can pass in parameters like `String`s or `Int`s, you can pass around functions too. The notation tells you what *parameters* the function takes, and what its *return value* is.

`(String) -> Unit` represents a function that has a single `String` parameter, and returns `Unit` (i.e. nothing). `(Int, Int) -> Int` represents a function that takes two `Int` parameters and returns a single `Int`. You can probably think of a few functions that match that!

Assuming you already know what an [*extension function*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) is (since you said this parameter was the bit you were confused about), then `T.() -> Unit` just represents a function you call on a *receiver* of type `T`, which takes no parameters, and returns `Unit`. It basically means you can do this:

```
"hi I'm a String".apply({ println(this) })
// or more usually, moving the lambda outside of the parentheses:
"hi I'm a String".apply { println(this) }
```

The lambda's type is `T.() -> Unit` - because you're calling `apply` on a `String`, that means `T` in this case is `String`. So your lambda's receiver, `this` in its scope, is a `String` - and you can make use of that in the lambda. It's usually used to configure something, e.g.

```
val myThing = SomeObject().apply {
    setOption(true)
    addMessage("Hi")
}
```

instead of

```
val myThing = SomeObject()
myThing.setOption(true)
myThing.addMessage("Hi")
```

See how the object can be excluded in the `apply` since it's the receiver, and you don't need to explicitly say `this`?

---

There are a bunch of these scope functions, like `apply`, `run`, `with` that all do something different in terms of what they return. `apply` returns the *original object*, not the result of the lambda - see how the function `T.() -> Unit` returns `Unit`, meaning any value you express will be ignored by `apply` (which returns the original object you called it on). `run` on the other hand, returns the result of the lambda, which could be a different type.

There are also equivalents that take a `parameter` instead of a `receiver` - e.g. `also` is the parameter equivalent of `apply`:

```
fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T
fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T
```

See how that works? Same deal, but if you use that with a `String`, it's accessible in the function as a *parameter* instead (named `it` by default for a single parameter). Which you use depends on what's appropriate for the situation, and whether you think a named parameter is more readable or not